# NuPIC .ova image installation - for Mac OS X (10.9)?

Tags: image, macos, installation, virtualbox, nupic

I just got a [4Gb image (.ova)](https://mega.co.nz/#!fQomTTqI!ffY_QBQQH5oGagylqpgScTzKPHF8Ef7yLFo3LboHzuk) created by [Marek](https://github.com/breznak) for VM - anyone successfully installed it on Mac OS X (10.9) ? Any additional recommendations ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have an incomplete image. I think that .ova file is supposed to be 6GB, but the mega.co.nz link errors out at 4GB. I have yet to be able to get the entire image as well.

..correction - I was looking at the NUPIC-03_11_2014.ova image issue.

Comment: Suggest you edit your answer to show what you are actually trying to say, as it's not obvious whether your "correction" bit means the first paragraph is valid or not. If it's not valid, simply delete your answer.